# Not getting the email from twitter using Fabric Twitter SDK

Tags: objective-c, twitter, twitter-fabric

This seems to be age old question with no specific answers or solutions for it. I had my application whitelisted from twitter. Done all the things. Checked the request email from user box and used the following code

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] startWithConsumerKey:@"FabricKey" consumerSecret:@"FabricSecretKey"];
if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]) {

    TWTRShareEmailViewController *shareEmailViewController =
    [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc]
     initWithCompletion:^(NSString *email, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Email %@ | Error: %@", email, error);
     }];

    [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
```

But still it is returning null. Why is this?? I even created the application in twitter developer portal. Please help me. Is twitter trying to be more over secure?? It is just pissing me out......